# Is it possible to use Laravel Fortify on a laravel package?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create a custom laravel package. I was wondering if I can directly use laravel fortify as dependency of that custom package. I need to modify fortify like the user table, user validation and etc without doing it again and again for every project that depends on it or touching fortify directly.

Comment: Hi, I'm wondering the same, have you found a solution?

Comment: Still haven't found the solution for this.